# Why doesn't LinkedHashMap keyset() return LinkedHashSet vs Set?

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap, linkedhashset

I've read in java documentation and also in this post that LinkedHashMaps' `keyset()` maintains order.
[Is the order guaranteed for the return of keys and values from a LinkedHashMap object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923856/is-the-order-guaranteed-for-the-return-of-keys-and-values-from-a-linkedhashmap-o)

My question is, if it guarantees order then why doesn't the source code of `LinkedHashMap` return an Object of type `Set` that guarantees order like `LinkedHashSet`?

One reason I can maybe think of is that LinkedHashSet uses a map which would increase memory allocation (depending on how AbstractSet is implemented). Is it also because it future proofs implementation of keyset?

Like this answer says in this post : [Is it better to use List or Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917627/is-it-better-to-use-list-or-collection)

> Returning a List is in line with programming to the Highest Suitable
>   Interface.
>
> Returning a Collection would cause ambiguity to the user, as a
>   returned collection could be either: Set, List or Queue.

So, without reading the documentation of the `keyset()` isn't this ambiguous?

`keyset()` source code:

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks = keySet;
    return (ks != null ? ks : (keySet = new KeySet()));
}

private final class KeySet extends AbstractSet<K> {
    public Iterator<K> iterator() {
        return newKeyIterator();
    }
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return containsKey(o);
    }
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return HashMap.this.removeEntryForKey(o) != null;
    }
    public void clear() {
        HashMap.this.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"why doesn't the source code of `LinkedHashMap` return an `Object` of type `Set` that guarantees order like `LinkedHashSet`?"*

Because `LinkedHashSet` is a concrete class with it's own implementation maintaining its own data, and the [`keyset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) method must return a view of the `Map`, so it cannot just copy the key data to a `LinkedHashSet`. See javadoc:

> Returns a `Set` view of the keys contained in this map. The **set is backed by the map**, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 5):

It returns a `Set` as defined by the `Map` interface. A `Set` is simply collection that contains no duplicate elements. On the other hand, a `List` is an ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The `List` interface does not specify that elements be unique.

Still, the `LinkedHashMap` implementation actually returns the underlying keySet which is a `LinkedKeySet`, and the `forEach()` method of the `LinkedKeySet` is order-preserving, i.e.:

```
//from the source code for the LinkedHashMap:
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks;
    return (ks = keySet) == null ? (keySet = new LinkedKeySet()) : ks;
}
```

So, in this case, the elements are both unique and ordered.

Comment: although your second portion is right, the first is not necessarily true  just because the Map interface specifies Set doesn't mean that it can't override with LinkedKeySet

Comment: My point was to highlight that the `LinkedKeySet` provides ordering over its elements. I didn't want to imply that a `Set` can't also implement the  `List` interface. @Andreas answer addresses your question of the "why"; I tried to address the *what do we do about it* side.

Answer (score 1):

> if it guarantees order then why doesn't the source code of LinkedHashMap return an Object of type Set that guarantees order like LinkedHashSet?

The *declared* type of the key set is drawn from that declared by `Map.keySet()`.  `LinkedHashMap` was added to the standard library before covariant return types were added to the Java language.  At that time, there was no alternative to using type `Set`.

In any event, just because the key set must have the same order as the underlying map does not mean that it must be a `LinkedHashSet`, and in fact it cannot be, because it must not support element additions.  Its class is instead a private nested class of class `LinkedHashMap`.  There is no public type between that class and `Set` that would be any more useful than `Set` as a return type.

Indeed, I don't think it would be easy to define one.  What would be the essential characteristics that distinguish it from any other set?  You cannot merely say "iteration order" without specifying *what* iteration order instances would have, and that order depends on the `LinkedHashMap` instance from which the set is obtained.  In other words, iteration order is an instance characteristic, not a class characteristic.  A declared type that expresses the nature of being the key set of a `LinkedHashMap` would therefore provide almost no information of any practical use beyond what `Set` provides.

Anyway, I do not find the excerpt you quoted about returning a `List` vs a `Collection` to be very persuasive.  The fact is that ambiguity about an object's specific class is not inherently a problem.  In the `Collection` vs. `List` example, if type `Collection` captures the return-type requirements of the method well, such that there is no particular reason that the characteristic features of a `List` are required, then `Collection` is a good choice of return type.  It is especially good if the requirements could also be satisfied by a `Set`, because then the API is not making an essentially arbitrary choice between two equally good alternatives.

There is a school of thought that holds that methods should be as general as possible in the types of their arguments and as specific as possible in their return types.  I attribute a lot of merit to that idea, but it is rather more of a guideline than a rule, and there is quite a lot of room for interpretation as to how specific "as specific as possible" is.

Answer (score 0):

Java 21 added the [`sequencedKeySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html#sequencedKeySet()) method to `LinkedHashMap`, which returns the key set as a [`SequencedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html) (i.e. a `Set` with a well-defined encounter order).  While the `keySet` method continues to be a `Set` to maintain backwards compatibility, the `sequencedKeySet` method returns the `SequencedKeySet` type that specifically guarantees a well-defined iteration order.